# How to add postcss-mixins on top of postcss-env-preset?

Tags: node.js, webpack, postcss

I want to add postcss-mixins to my project running fine with postcss-env-preset, tried but mixins are not working, below is my postcss.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const postcssPresetEnv = require('postcss-preset-env')
const mqpacker = require('css-mqpacker')
const postcssMixins = require('postcss-mixins')
module.exports = {
    plugins:  [
        postcssMixins(),
        new postcssPresetEnv(
            {
                stage: 0,
                importFrom: path.resolve(__dirname, "./util/global.css")
            }
        ),
        mqpacker({
            sort: function (a, b) {
                return a.localeCompare(b);
            }
        }),

    ]
}
```

output css files simply let the @mixins line untouched:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4w51.png